# Ruby 1.9.3 - Savon and NTLM Authentication

Tags: ruby, ntlm

I am trying to use a web service client for some web services using SOAP. I used the soap4r but with not results on the NTLM authentication. Any advice on how to setup this with the Savon Gem.

Environment: Ruby 1.9.3 and Windows 7

Comment: By the way using Ruby 1.9.1/Rubysspi/Soap4r(custom fixed) it worked. The problem i dont want to depend on custom fixes for this kind of requirements.

Comment: I'd be interested in whether my pull request for Savon works in your environment.  Can you [try it out](https://github.com/coldnebo/httpi/wiki)?  Thanks!  Also, note this is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050567/ntlm-support-for-savon

Comment: I can try but i found it easy to consume a .net web service using Powershell and process the ouput from ruby. Not a powershell fan but is working now.

Comment: yep, that will work too. IronRuby might be another way as well.

Comment: i was wondering if there is s ruby wrapper somewhere to make powershell calls and process output.