# NTLM support for Savon

Tags: sharepoint, ntlm, savon

I'm using Savon to communicate with SharePoint using web services. Everything is working fine if SharePoint web application supports basic authentication, but if I change it to NTLM it fails. It fails at line

```
newclient.http.auth.ntlm(username, password)
```

and the error message is `Install the httpi-ntlm gem for experimental NTLM support`. FYI I have allready installed the specified gem and am using it.

Comment: I also had some trouble using the experimental branch in this context.  Would you mind [testing this fork](https://github.com/coldnebo/httpi/wiki) and letting me know if it works for you?  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Larry, i tried your link but its not working for me, Please let me know is there any alternative.

Comment: Just tried this with my external app and noticed a missing require that didn't show up during the tests.  I've fixed it now, try updating. Thanks!